# How to get predictive attributes of each target in `Random Forest`?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

I've been messing around with `Random Forest` models lately and they are really useful w/ the `feature_importance_` attribute!

**It would be useful to know which variables are more predictive of particular targets.**

For example, what if the `1st and 2nd attributes` were more predictive of distringuishing `target 0` but the `3rd and 4th attributes` were more predictive of `target 1`?

**Is there a way to get the `feature_importance_` array for each target separately?** With `sklearn`, `scipy`, `pandas`, or `numpy` preferably.

```
# Iris dataset
DF_iris = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data,
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names)

Se_iris = pd.Series(load_iris().target,
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       name = "Species")
# Import modules
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

# Split Data
X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(DF_iris, Se_iris, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Create model
Mod_rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
Mod_rf.fit(X_tr,y_tr)

# Variable Importance
Mod_rf.feature_importances_
# array([ 0.14334485,  0.0264803 ,  0.40058315,  0.42959169])

# Target groups
Se_iris.unique()
# array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about specific targets, but incase you haven't checked already xgboost has an overall feature importance attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really how RF works. Since there is no simple "feature voting" (which takes place in linear models) it is really hard to answer the question what "feature X is more predictive for target Y" even means. What feature_importance of RF captures is "how probable is, in general, to use this feature in the decision process". The problem with addressing your question is that if you ask "how probable is, in general, to use this feature in decision process **leading to label Y**" you would have to pretty much run the same procedure but remove all subtrees which do not contain label Y in a leaf - this way you remove parts of the decision process which do not address the problem "is it Y or not Y" but rather try to answer which "not Y" it is. However, in practice, due to very stochastic nature of RF, cutting its depth etc. this might barely reduce anything. The bad news is also, that I never seen it implemented in any standard RF library, you could do this on your own, just the way I said:

```
for i = 1 to K (K is number of distinct labels)
  tmp_RF = deepcopy(RF)
  for tree in tmp_RF:
    tree = remove_all_subtrees_that_do_not_contain_given_label(tree, i)
    for x in X (X is your dataset)
      features_importance[i] += how_many_times_each_feature_is_used(tree, x) / |X| 
  features_importance[i] /= |tmp_RF|
return features_importance
```

in particular you could use existing feature_importance codes, simply by doing

```
for i = 1 to K (K is number of distinct labels)
  tmp_RF = deepcopy(RF)
  for tree in tmp_RF:
    tree = remove_all_subtrees_that_do_not_contain_given_label(tree, i)
  features_importance[i] = run_regular_feature_importance(tmp_RF)
return features_importance
```

Comment: Hey @lejlot thanks for your answer!  Still need to decipher some of the meaning in it to fully understand what you're talking about.  What exactly is a `deepcopy`?

Comment: By deepcopy i mean a copy that is recursive, to make sure you have a copy of each tree, not just copy of references

Comment: Woah, like a copy of each decision tree in the random forest?

Comment: yes, since you are going to modify it. Of course instead of doing a copy you can just traverse each one to collect needed elements without modifying. Up to you. This is just implementation detail

Comment: Is it possible to traverse the individual trees from a `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifer` object?

Comment: @lejlot , please help me with this. Suppose we have `3 vars: v1, v2, v3` and `2 PCs: PC1, PC2`. `PC1` has a contribution of `0.8` and `PC2` has the same of `0.2`. In the principal coefficient matrix, we have the significance of each var for each PC. Let's say we get: `PC1 -> (v1: 0.46, v2: 0.02, v3: 0.51)` and `PC2 -> (v1: 0.2, v2: -0.12, v3: 0.3)`. What can you say about the relative importance of `v1, v2, v3`?

Comment: @O.rka yes but it is not trivial, you have to go through source code of rf predict operation and see how it traverses the trees and do the same. Ketan - this is unrelated to the question or answer, please ask a separate question and I will try to adress your concerns. As it requires much more from space than a comment section

Comment: @lejlot, in spite of whatever you say, this is a relevant and related discussion. I don't need to hear theories. If you can, replying `whether v2 is least important for predicting the target variable in the example above or not` - yes or no - is not going to need much more space.

Comment: @ketan the short answer is that the pca based analysis has no sense for this problem. You cannot say anything reaspnable about imprtance from the classification perspective. Term "importance" have completely dofferent meaning when used in terms of pca and classification.

Comment: @lejlot, your response doesn't make any sense to me and for my example. Choosing to sign off from this little thread.

Comment: @ketan In PCA importance is in terms of variance.  Suppose you had a plane in 2D and projected it into 3D.  The dimension with the least amount of variance would be that 3rd dimension since it doesn't contain any information.  However, if you have a different situation where each dimension contained information then the principal components that contain the explained variance you're talking about would each be project into a direction in between the original axis.  Does that make sense?  Because of this, one can't assign v1 to the first PC.